# Issue while creating user for a specific database through code in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am creating a copy of database in Azure through c# code.

Code for creating database:

```
CREATE DATABASE ABC AS COPY OF DEF
```

Then I want to create a user in that database so that only that user can access the database. This code executes as soon as the database is created. but while creating a user I get an error:

```
"failed to update database because the database is read only".
```

If I stop the execution for 15-20 seconds, then start, it works perfectly, but I don't want to do that.

Can I get some status that the database is created and you can proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're connecting to your database and executing T-SQL, you may have to use a query against [sys.dm_operation_status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270022.aspx) and find your Create Database command and whether it has completed. There may be an associated [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163571.aspx) if you choose to program this through REST calls, there is a [Get Create or Update Server Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt644762.aspx) call which might fit your scenario.

You will find that the new database will take some time to create and you won't exit that logic instantly in either approach.

Comment: Thank u Dan.  The Issue got solved when I used the Api.

Comment: Glad to hear it, hope you find success using SQL Azure